# line continuation in intersystems cache objectscript

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

I am writing in intersystems cache object script.
I have a statement which has become very long.
Is there any way to continue a statement in the next line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post a sample?
If you have a long string you can concatenate it like this:

```
Set SQL = "SELECT * "_
          "FROM Sample.Person "_
          "WHERE Name [ 'a'"
```

This is equal to:

```
Set SQL = "SELECT * FROM Sample.Person WHERE Name [ 'a'"
```

Other types of statements can also be placed on several lines.